# Return value from function to calling function in different file Node.JS

Tags: node.js, function, methods, promise, return

I have a need to call a method within another file and return the output from the method back to the originating caller.

I have tried using various callback methods, promises, and so on with no  luck. Below is the function/method I am calling.

````js
methods.sdata = function gather_data(path, body) {
    var d = new Object();
    var initializePromise = initialize_session();
    initializePromise.then(function(result) {
        sessionID = result;
        //console.log("Initialized sessionID");
        //console.log(sessionID)
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }).then(function(data_result){
    var initializePromise = set_data(path, body, sessionID);
    initializePromise.then(function(result) {
        data = result;
        return data
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
    })
}```

I am calling the method/function above from another file. I need to pass back the data variable once complete.
````

Comment: Return your `promise` from this function and then `.then` it in the "other" file

Answer (score 0):

You are messing things with promises, better simply return a promise from your main method and use async/await to handle asynchronous methods in promise, the code for same will be:

```
methods.sdata = function gather_data(path, body) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const d = new Object();
            const intSessionResult = await initialize_session();                        // initialize session
            const { sessionID = '' } = intSessionResult;                                // get session id from init session result 
            const setDataResult = await set_data(path, body, sessionID);                // set session id
            resolve(setDataResult);                                                     // return data back to calling method
        } catch(err) {
            reject(err);                                                                // returns error in case any
        }
    });
}
```

and then you can call it like a promise using then and catch. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Amir Ansari that makes perfect sense. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad it helps ... Happy Coding ;)